# How do I find $P(X + Y < 1)$?

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables, with $f(x, y) = 1$, then what is $P(X + Y < 1)$?

Our teacher said it's $$\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_x^{1-x}1 \cdot dy dx.$$

I'm confused about the limits of integration and would some please explain how we in general decide on the limits in such problems?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram of the region in the X-Y plane?

Comment: There is certainly something missing in your question: a density of $f(x,y)=1$ is necessarily restricted to a set with measure one. What is this set?!

Comment: You have not supplied any information concerning how the limits of integration would be determined--you have simply given the answer, not the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $f(x,y)=1$, then for it to be a probability distribution $(X,Y)$ must be defined in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an area 1. There are multiple such sets and the answer depends on it. Let us assume that $(X,Y)$ belong to a unit square $\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2\}$. Then the probability $P(X+Y<1)$ is defined as following:

$$\int\int_{\{x+y<1\}\cap\{0\le x,y\le 1\}}1\cdot dxdy$$

Here are graphs illustrating the sets:

[image]

The square in the left hand plot is the domain and the lower shaded triangle is the integrating area.  The right hand plot shows the domain specified in the question.

Comment: Gah, the initial version had a bad graph.

Comment: (+1) FWIW, the graphic was produced with the *Mathematica* command `GraphicsRow[
 {
  RegionPlot[x + y <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, BaseStyle -> Medium, 
   PlotLabel -> "x + y < 1" ],
  RegionPlot[0 <= x <= 1/2 && x <= y <= 1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, BaseStyle -> Medium, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "x < 1/2 and x < y < 1-x"]
  }]`